# What is the best way to store objects in React Native; redux-persist or localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I want to store some data in my react native app.
Which one is the best practice; `redux-persist` or `localStorage`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer,  @slideshowp2. I am using Redux in my app, then it's the best practice to use `redux-persist`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` is one of the store engines for `redux-persist`. See https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines. They are not the same thing and cannot be compared. `redux-persist` is in addition to the storage engine, Redux persist ships with react integration as a convenience, and generally speaking, it is enough to use.

`redux-persist` provides some state Reconciler strategies that can help you reconcile states easily.

You can decide which state slice should be persisted to the store engine using Blacklist & Whitelist feature.